# PlotlyJS 3d cones

Tags: julia, plotly

I am using Julia and PlotlyJS in it , to do some velocity field plots by using the cone track in a 3d plot.

Is there a way to have the size of the cones set by a list of numbers (length = #cones)?

Code:

```
function plot_av(res::DataFrame, n::Int)
    """
    Function to plot the average velocity field

    Inputs:
       - res:: Dataframe for cells properties
       - n:: minimum number of stars in cell
    """

    res_full = res[res[:n_star] .> n-1, :]

    # Galactic Centre

    t0 = scatter3d(; x = [0], y = [0], z = [0], mode = "markers",
                 marker = attr(color = "#000000", 
                 size = 4, symbol = "cross", opacity = 1), 
                 name = "Galactic Center")


     # Average speed; 
     fields = Dict{Symbol,Any}(:type => "cone",
                      :x => collect(res_full[:x_cell]),
                      :y => collect(res_full[:y_cell]),
                      :z => collect(res_full[:z_cell]),
                      :u => collect(res_full[:u_mean]),
                      :v => collect(res_full[:v_mean]),
                      :w => collect(res_full[:w_mean]),
                      :sizemode => "absolute",
                      :sizeref => 100,
                      :colorscale => "Greens"
      )

     tvel = GenericTrace("cone", fields)

     layout = Layout(autosize=false, width=800, height=800, 
     margin=attr(l=0, r=0, b=0, t=65))

     plot([t0, tvel], layout)
end
```

I tried setting `:sizeref` to an array but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:sizeref is used by the Plotly routine with source code here:
https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/traces/cone/attributes.js

which seems to be defined and used as a single number. So this limitation seems to be one within Plotly. So, I don't think an array can be used by PlotlyJS here.